# Dejar espacio alrededor de la pagina

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

La pagina hecha con bootstrap se me pega al borde de la pantalla, ¿cómo puedo dejar un espacio?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Theme Template for Bootstrap</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleFormNavBar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header collapse navbar-collapse">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">navbar-inverse</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <img src="ims/logo2.jpg" height="50" width="50"> 
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li ><a href="#">Solicitudes</a></li> <!--class="active" -->
            <li><a href="#">Certificados</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Administrativo</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Reportes</a></li>            
            <li><a href="#">Estado de Trámites</a></li>   
            <li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</li>  
            <li><button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right">Iniciar Sesión</button>   </li>      
          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slides">
        <div class="slide">
          <img src="ims/11.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="ims/22.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="ims/33.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <img src="ims/44.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div onclick="goLeft()" class="btnLeft fas fa-chevron-left"></div>
      <div onclick="goRight()" class="btnRight fas fa-chevron-right"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#"> Solicitudes</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
             <img src="ims/funcionario.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="#l">Certificados</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/carta_laboral.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="cesantias.html">Reportes</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/reporte.png" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="permisos.html">Estado de Trámites</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/tramite.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="capacitacion.html">Iniciar Sesión</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/cerradura.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><a href="nomina.html">Administrativo</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <img src="ims/novedades.jpg" height="200" width="320">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->



      <div class="footer" >        
        <div class="col-sm-7">
          <div >
          <strong>Hospital General de Medellín</strong><br>
          El Hospital General de Medellín es una Empresa Social del Estado que presta servicios de salud hasta la alta complejidad, centrados en la seguridad del paciente, brindando afecto, confianza, satisfacción y promoviendo buenas prácticas ambientales y de calidad.
          </div> 
        </div>    
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div > Conmutador: (574) 384 7300 Fax: (574) 232 0227<br>
              Carrera 48 No.32 - 102 Medellín - Colombia<br>
              Código postal 0500515<br>
              contacto@hgm.gov.co   <br><br>           

          </div>     
        </div>      
      </div><!-- footer -->      


    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  var index = 0;
  function goLeft() {
    if(index == 0) index = slides.length - 1;
    else index--;

    slides[0].style.marginLeft = "-" + index * 1100 + "px";
  }
  function goRight() {
    if(index == slides.length -1) index = 0;
    else index++;

    slides[0].style.marginLeft = "-" + index * 1100 + "px";
  }

  //for auto Navigation
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

¿Estaría bien un espacio a la izquierda?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, tienes 2 formas de hacerlo, una poniendo paddings en el html, o saber lo basico de bootstrap, que es metiendo el contenido en un `<div class="container"></div>`. Tambien puede ser class container-fluid. Despues del slider tienes `row`, pero estas necesitan un contenedor

Comment: Viendo la imagen que agregaste, creo que la mejor solucion es la que menciona @FranciscoGarrido, deberias encapsular tu `row` dentro de un `<div class="container">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con las siguientes clases podrás hacer `margin` o `padding` (espaciado externo e interno):

`Margin right y left` (espaciado externo, ambos lados):

```
<div class="mx-5 my-5"></div>
```

O simplemente:

```
<div class="m-5"></div>
```

O con `padding`:

```
<div class="p-5"></div>
```

O con `container` y `container-fluid`:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

> Estos dos últimos harán un margen horizontal (x).

Agregando alguna de esas clases a un `div` en especifico harás que este tenga un espaciado en sus lados, te recomiendo que veas la documentación de la pagina de `Bootstrap 4`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más fácil que puedes hacer es consumir Bootstrap y en el Body poner una sección con clase container.

```
<body>
   <section class="container">
      <!--Tú código-->
   </section>
</body>
```